# grid table with a to z indexes

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

```
                             <sjg:grid 
             id="sample_grid"
             caption="Patient List"
             dataType="json"
                     `href="%{loadGrid}"
                  pager="true"
             hidegrid="false"
             gridModel="gridData"
             rowList="10,15,20"
             rowNum="10"


             viewrecords="true"
             autowidth="true"
             shrinkToFit="true"
             sortable="false"
             navigatorAdd="false"
                 navigatorDelete="false"
                  navigatorEdit="false"
             navigatorRefresh="false"
             navigatorSearch="false"
             navigatorView="false">                             
          <sjg:gridColumn name="name" index="Name" title="Name"/>
          <sjg:gridColumn name="age" index="Age" title="Age"/>
          <sjg:gridColumn name="country" index="Country" title="Country" />
 </sjg:grid>
```

'

help me to add an toolbar in top the grid table which consists of a to z characters as a index. On clicking any of the character the data (for eg. names) starting with that character should be listed in the grid table .see above for the code that I am using....

Comment: On searching I got that we can add a footerrow to this grid but confused how to add data to that footer